# How do you add a Google Maps route to "My Maps"?

Tags: google-maps, google-my-maps

After creating a route I'm happy with, how do I save it to "My Maps"?  I used to know how to do this but things look different now.

I found directions which seem to be out of date: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-save-directions-from-google-maps

There, I read

> Scroll down to the bottom of the driving directions. Click "Save to My Maps."

But when I scroll down to the bottom of the driving directions, I don't see "Save to My Maps."

Comment: @Aʟᴇ - Okay, but then how do you save a route?  I have looked at all the doohickies on the screen and have experimented with right-clicking here and there, and am not finding a way to do that.  Apparently they want you to go to My Maps and start your route creation process from scratch.

Comment: I can't check at the moment, but if I recall it just saves your latest route. Try clicking in the search box. I'll see if I can expand on that a bit later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've chosen a route, after you click on "Details", you have a couple of options:

- Send to your phone

  - Depending on your device, you can get the directions sent to the Google Maps on your phone, sent to email, or sent via text
- Share

  - a link
  - code to embed a map on a web page
- Print

  - with or without mini maps

It seems to me that the simplest option for coming back to directions later is to get the link and save the link somewhere. There is even an option to shorten the link, so you can get something like https://goo.gl/maps/unAMRv2oXQL2 instead of https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Mets-Willets+Point/Sag+Harbor,+NY/@40.8383632,-73.6327663,9z/am=t/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c25fdf0a2e25f3:0x3abb28977780008d!2m2!1d-73.8437!2d40.75239!1m5!1m1!1s0x89e8bd23cca70ca7:0xd8ff0f5b96c0899d!2m2!1d-72.2925819!2d40.9978773

Answer (score 6):

Or, similar to the above, In **Google Maps** next to the "Send to your phone button" is a button for "**Share link**"
Copy the web address it provides and Paste it into the web site **Maps to GPX** https://mapstogpx.com/
Press the "**Let's Go**" button and a GPX file will be downloaded to your PC. Go to **My Maps**, create a **New Map** and click on **Import** to import the GPX file and voila you can save your map.

Comment: Oh my goodness.  The old way was much more direct.

Comment: thanks very much. this worked. on the other hand, it would be very nice if Google integrated this functionality with the Maps and My Maps.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - in fact, it's the only answer that actually answers the question! As an added bonus, saving a route to a .gpx opens up a huge range of nav options, not just My Maps.

Answer (score 1):

My Maps is neither phased out or shut down.

But it is now a completely separate product.   You can still use it to plot and share routes.    But you need to start at MyMaps (https://www.google.com/maps)  not regular Google Maps to access it:  there is no way (AFAIK) to transfer a plotted route from Google Maps to My Maps.

Comment: Any predictions as to how much longer MyMaps will continue to exist?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine.   But I'm not expecting it to be closed down soon- it enables people to add individual content to Google Maps in a curated way, and it's the tool for letting people embed routes or sets of points in their own websites.   (If you try that from regular Google Maps, your website views set their own set of points on the map, not yours).    So I'm continuing to develop niche websites using it.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options within Google Maps. You can save the destination address to your list of places before doing the route, then do the route each time you want to start. This is the most work, but allows flexibility in starting point. You can do the route, then touch the 3 vertical dots and share the route to your device via e-mail or other option (text directions can be used offline). You can do the route, then touch the 3 vertical dots and save a shortcut to the route to your device home screen (requires full time data service).

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is to use GPS Visualizer (gpsvisualizer.com) to convert the route on Google Maps to a GPX file (save it on computer). Then import the file to My Maps.